# Is an enterprise app distribution provisioning profile tied to specific devices / do devices need to have the profile installed?

Tags: ios, provisioning

According to the Apple documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

In the steps listed to create an enterprise app it says:

```
Create an enterprise distribution provisioning profile *that authorizes devices* to use apps you’ve signed.
```

(My emphasis)

If the provisioning profile authorizes devices how is that done? I mean is the profile associated with specific devices somehow - I read elsewhere but don't have the reference that the devices need to have this profile installed. 
Is that correct, if it is then how do the devices get the profile installed?

Comment: See my answer below.  The profiles are included in the application ipa file when distributed.  If deploying for development, the profile will be added when the device is added to the developer portal (this is done in Xcode -> Organizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the proper distribution certificates installed and the provisioning profiles associated with the Dist certs added to Xcode, then you will Archive the application making sure you have specified the proper prov profiles in the Build Setting tab of the Target properties.  See image below:

[image: Build Settings]

Then you will Archive the application and choose to distribute via Enterprise deployment.  You give it the path to the app executable (URL) that you plan to put the app and the .plist that will accompany it (both will get built automagically for you).  See images below:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

Then you can just use a url to the plist file for your users to download / install the application you built.

For my employer, I created our own internal "app store" where all our iOS applications are housed for our users.  This way, they download / install one app from a web server and get all the rest of the applications (including any updates) via our "app store" app.

I can help you out with a complete infrastructure if you need, but the idea is simple.