# How to distribute iPad app as in-house app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, in-house-distribution

I developed some 3 apps for my organization and we want to distribute it to some 30 iPads in the office. I am tying to find a step by step process to do it. But didn't find any so far. The methods I tried and failed are the following,

1. I took the app (with .app extension which can be found in ~/Library/Developer/../IOs_Release) and provisional certificate and dropped them in iTunes library. After that I connected a new iPad (not a registered as development device) to my mac book. Through itunes, I tried to sync the app. But an alert appeared on the ipad showing "xyz app is failed to install"
2. I tried the ad hoc distribution. First I archived app in the xcode archive and clicked distribute button. A wizard appeared asking for what kind of distribution do I want. I selected ad-hoc distribution and it automatically selected my iPhone distribution certificate  and processed and gave me .ipa file. I tried installing it in the iPad by itunes sync and it gave me same error.

It would be great to get steps for in-house app distribution since they are nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my answer to another person's SO question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317307/is-an-enterprise-app-distribution-provisioning-profile-tied-to-specific-devices/13317683#13317683)

This assumes that your organization is setup with an Enterprise developer account.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you take into account the OP's comment on the other question.  What OP wants to do is impossible without an Enterprise account.  An enterprise account will need to be approved by Apple which means a company of decent size needs to apply for it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called iOS Beta Builder, check the below links:
[Introducing iOS Beta Builder](http://www.hanchorllc.com/2010/08/24/introducing-ios-beta-builder/)
[iOS Beta Builder GitHub page](https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder)
[iOS Beta Builder Mac AppStore](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ios%20beta%20builder%20app%20store&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGwQFjAI&url=https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/betabuilder-for-ios-apps/id415348946?mt=12&ei=rcWfUKGpMMSF4ATEuIGYDA&usg=AFQjCNEpd_M2akqJWTH2mEq55TNfDf9AlQ)

Answer (score 0):

The provisioning profile used for the adhoc build must have a reference to the 30 devices.

Go to the [Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) and add all 30 devices under the Devices section.

Then add those devices to the adhoc provisioning profile (Provisioning, Distribution).

Once added, download the updated provisioning profile and install it in Xcode. Delete any previous profile.

Build and Archive the app. Make sure the archive build is properly setup to use your adhoc provisioning profile.

Use the Organizer to save the ipa file from the archive build.

Drop the ipa file into iTunes. Now sync each of the 30 devices to include the app.

Comment: I am looking for a method, that doesn't require any registering or adding the devices

Comment: Other than possibly jailbreaking, you can't do this without adding each of the devices. This is how Apple allows you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode - Product -> Archive**

Distribute -> (Select) Save for enterprise or Ad-Hoc Development (Next)-> Code sign identity (select your profile)-> save File on disk -> distribute project.ipa file.